# Possible to reference elements with class names & only inside a specific DIV with an ID & not have to use the ID name beforehand i.e #ID .classname?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Say my css looks like so:

```
#StoreIndexMain .LeftSideControl
{
    padding-top: 35px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    width:78px;
    float:left;
    height: 58em;

}

#StoreIndexMain .LeftSideControl:Hover
{

    opacity: .6;
     background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

I was hoping maybe there's something like:

```
#StoreIndexMain
(

.LeftSideControl {}


.LeftSideControl:Hover {}

)
```

Comment: Yes, use LESS or SASS as your CSS preprocessor

Comment: Not sure how I missed Raynos comment before editing my own answer upon remembering SASS, but a thousand times 'yes'. There's nothing wrong with using a CSS preprocessor to get this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Every selector is an independent unit. CSS doesn't (currently) allow for that type of selector specification (though I can see where it might prove useful; put in a recommendation for the next CSS specification and let the community have at it).

**Edit:** However, in the interim you can use a CSS preprocessor to get such features. [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) is one such popular preprocessor. This particular feature would be [Nesting](http://sass-lang.com/#nesting).